# Hunspell for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, hunspell

I am trying install Hunspell on ES 2.3, Ubuntu 16.4.

Downloaded zip from http://download.services.openoffice.org/contrib/dictionaries/, extracted to ES root `/etc/elasticsearch`. Dictionary location `/etc/elasticsearch/config/hunspell/cs_CZ/cs_CZ.(dic|aff)`.

Add new line `indices.analysis.hunspell.dictionary.location: /etc/elasticsearch` to `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`, but 
after elasticsearch restart still error:

> Guice Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: please, put your hunspell dictionaries under config/hunspell !

Answer (score 3):

I am sure you figured it out by now, but here is another way to install Hunspell

1. If you using zipped version (not dockerized), just drop Hunspell folder under config/ and restart the service
2. If you are using dockerized container and if you haven't changed the default locations (/etc/elasticsearch) for config folder, then just drop Hunspell to /etc/elasticsearch. If you are running as some user(UID/GID), then don't forget to own the folder. Something like this below in Dockerfile:

   ```
   COPY config /etc/elasticsearch/

   RUN set -ex \
       && for path in \
           /etc/elasticsearch/ \
       ; do \
           mkdir -p "$path"; \
           chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch "$path"; \
       done
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You must put your hunspell dictionaries under **config/hunspell** in the elasticsearch.yml as the **error means**.